# Updating a single cell for a key in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to iterate through items in a dataframe and update the current row.

I am iterating ( rather than using df.apply ) as I need to process files based on the values in the dataframe. Note: for various reasons I do not want to use df.apply here.

`df` is the dataframe

```
for key,item in df.iterrows():
    df.xs(key)['downloaded']=True
```

if I do

```
df[:5]
```

the field 'downloaded' hasn't been updated (It shows as False). How do I get this to update correctly?

Essentially what I want to do is update a single column value for a given key.

Comment: Why are you using `xs`? Are you slicing a `MultiIndex`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Phillip Cloud points out, `loc` is better for this job. And if you specify the key as a tuple, you can multi-index set as well.

```
In [2]: mi = DataFrame(dict(
         A = np.arange(5).astype(np.float64), 
         B = np.arange(5).astype(np.int64)),
            index=MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuple(zip(*[['bar','bar','baz','baz','baz'],['one','two','one','two','three']])),names=['first','second']))

In [3]: mi
Out[3]: 
              A  B
first second      
bar   one     0  0
      two     1  1
baz   one     2  2
      two     3  3
      three   4  4

In [4]: mi.loc[('baz','two'),'B'] = -5

In [5]: mi
Out[5]: 
              A  B
first second      
bar   one     0  0
      two     1  1
baz   one     2  2
      two     3 -5
      three   4  4
```

Answer (score 0):

`xs()` creates a copy of your data by default, so to modify the original data, you should pass `copy=False`:

```
for key,item in df.iterrows():
    df.xs(key, copy=False)['downloaded']=True
```

Comment: This kind of chained assignment is *not* recommended. It's much more clear to do `df.loc[key, 'downloaded'] = True`. That doesn't work for `key`s that are multidimensional though. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy. O